# Using XDK, how do I link to another page? Hyperlinks are disabled

Tags: hyperlink, intel-xdk

Edit: so apparently adding class="button" make it work... Can someone provide a reference on what other classes are there? We can't find any information on this.. Thanks

We are making an app in HTML5 using XDK, it has quite a few different views. We were planning to just link to another html page each time we want to go to a different view. But we quickly found out that hyperlinking does not work,  is disabled, and button does not link either.

One of the people in my group said she saw an example about having a bunch of  and then just show and hide them and use that as UI navigation... is that the only way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The XDK uses the App Framework UI framework by default.  Are you are looking for instructions on how to create a series of pages using that?

Answer (score 7):

The Intel XDK doesn't insert any class definitions or require that you use a specific framework. It is a tool for assembling an HTML5 hybrid mobile app using the CSS, HTML and JS files that you supply.

If you look at the samples and the default "blank" project that is created when you create a new project you'll see that there may be references to one or more of the following "phantom" JS files:

```
intelxdk.js
cordova.js
xhr.js
```

The first two (intelxdk.js and cordova.js) are special "device API" JavaScript libraries. You won't actually find them in your project directory, they are automatically included when you use the emulator and when you build your project (which "wraps up" your HTML5 code and assets into a native wrapper that is specific to the target you are building -- it does not compile anything, it just converts it into a hybrid native/HTML5 container app that can be installed on the target platform that you built for).

The third one is a special helper JS library for dealing with CORS issues from within your app.

None of these three JS files define any classes or HTML tags, etc. They simply implement target-specific device APIs that consist of JavaScript on the "top end" and native code on the "bottom end." Your application only sees and interacts with the JavaScript interface, and only with the APIs that you need to use (which is totally optional).

For an intro to all of this, please see the [Intel XDK Documentation page](http://www.intel.com/software/xdkdocs).

So, that means you determine which frameworks and structure your app takes. In other words, if you want to use Bootstrap and jQuery you can do so. If you decide to use the App Designer or the App Starter tools, they will define some classes that impact your layout. However, you are not required to use these tools to define your HTML and CSS, you can do it by hand or use your favorite UI framework library.

Keep in mind that your code is not being rendered by a desktop browser but the embedded "webview" that is part of the device. These webviews don't have the same memory and CPU resources that you're used to working with in a desktop browser, so you need to learn to be "lean and mean" for the best results. You are using HTML5 technologies to build a mobile app -- not creating a web site on a phone.

Hope this helps, please [see our HTML5 web site](http://software.intel.com/html5) for more background material. It's a little slim right now, but we're adding examples and background material as time and resources permit.

Hope that helps...

Comment: p.s. The webview HTML5 feature support can vary from OS version to version and from vendor to vendor. For example, Android 2.3 vs Android 4.0 and HTC versus Samsung versus iOS, etc.

Comment: but then, how you go to a page2.html from an element in page1.html ?

Comment: You should build a single-page app (SPA). Multi-page apps do not work well in the webview environment (they are possible, but not advised). See this doc page for some guidelines: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/guide_next_index.md.html#Next%20Steps